# In obiee rpd getting an errorThe content filter of a source for logical table: references multiple dimensions

Tags: obiee

In RPD i am creating an alias for the existing dimension and pulling it to RPD,Creating a hierarchy and joining with the logical fact but its throwing error as 'The content filter of a source for logical table: references multiple dimensions'.
Already some aliases are created for the same dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an alias in your `RPD` for example you have a fact table with 2 dates `Order date` and `Shipping date` in this case you need to join the time dimension with `Order date` and `Shipping date` but `OBIEE` doesn't support a multiple join with a dimension in this case you need to create an alias for the time dimension. The question how can i do it ? in `Physical schema of your RPD` right click of dimension that you need to have an alias an go to `New object` and then `alias` for more information visit this link as bellow 
[Alias in RPD OBIEE](http://dwhlaureate.blogspot.com/2013/07/advantages-of-using-alias-table-in-obiee.html)